# How to post a large image to user's Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, canvas, share

I am building a site that lets users browse 3d images. I have added a facebook share button. That button works, but it shares the URL and only a small thumbnail (the thumbnail only works sometimes).

Is it possible to create a button that shares a large custom image, in the same way that you upload a photo to your own timeline?

I cannot use meta tags, because the images change through javascript.
I also cannot let facebook find the image automatically, because it is rendered in a canvas 3d viewer [on the webpage](http://www.nightoferror.nl).

Thanks in advance!